# How can I use stash->parse in my extension

Tags: stash, add-on-development, extension, parse

I'm writing an addon which can take an EE template, replace some variables and then *crucially* parse the EE tags in it and then email it.

I was hoping stash:parse might come to my rescue after a day of poking around various addons code and other options.

So here's what I want to do:

```
echo "Template following process 1: $msg_body<br>";

  if ( ! class_exists('Stash'))
  &#123;
      include_once PATH_THIRD . 'stash/mod.stash.php';
  &#125;

  $stash = new Stash(TRUE); // instantiate with initialising

  $params = array(
   'process' => 'inline',
   'parse_depth' => 5
  );

  $parsed_string = $stash->parse($params, $msg_body);

  echo "Template following process 2: $parsed_string<br>";

  return $parsed_string;
```

This all seems to work - $msg_body is my template ready to parse. It contains a channel entries tag, which even when I make it as basic as possible, still gives the following error:

```
Error

The following tag has a syntax error:

&#123;exp:channel:entries&#125;

Please correct the syntax in your template.
```

The template code is
[code]{entry_id}
{exp:channel:entries
 channel="clients" 
 entry_id="18813" 
 status="not closed"
}
 {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}[/code]

So unless I've missed something obvious, there isn't a syntax error here.

It seems like this should work, especially as the parse example includes a channel entries tag (https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/{exp:stash:parse})

I put together a quick function in my module called "test_stash" which DOES work.

```
    function test_stash(){
    if ( ! class_exists('Stash'))
    {
        include_once PATH_THIRD . 'stash/mod.stash.php';
    }

    $msg_body = '
```

{exp:channel:entries
    channel="clients" 
    entry_id="18813" 
    status="not closed"
}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}';

```
    $stash = new Stash(TRUE); // instantiate with initialising

    $params = array(
        'process' => 'inline',
        'parse_depth' => 5
    );

    $parsed_string = $stash->parse($params, $msg_body);

    echo $parsed_string;

}
```

So it seems like the issue is with parsing the tag in my EXTENSION. Is there anything about this which could be causing an issue?

The extension fires on channel_form_submit_entry_end.

Any help/advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Quick update - having looked at what causes this error, I found that if I call

```
ee()->TMPL->fetch_addons();
```

in my extension before I call stash->parse, it works fine without an issue. Hope this helps someone.